# How do I setup Id of entity with a ConventionBuilder in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have following fluent configuration

```
var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                             .Database(configuration)
                             .Mappings(arg =>
                             {
                                 var autoMap = AutoMap.Source(typeSource);
                                 foreach (var convention in typeSource.GetConventions())
                                 {
                                     autoMap.Conventions.Add(convention);
                                 }
                                 autoMap.BuildMappings();
                             })
                             .BuildSessionFactory();
```

I use an instance (`typeSource`) of `FluentNHibernate.ITypeSource` that also has a method `GetConventions`, which returns `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<FluentNHibernate.Conventions.IConvention>`.

The result of `GetConventions` is then used to be injected into `Conventions` of `FluentNHibernate.Automapping.Automap` (in the `Mappings`-method of the fluent configuration).

A concrete implementation of `GetConventions` looks like

```
public override System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<FluentNHibernate.Conventions.IConvention> GetConventions()
{
    yield return FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.ConventionBuilder.Property.When(
          arg => arg.Expect(f => f.Type == typeof (string)),
          arg => arg.CustomType<CUSTOMTYPE>()
    );
}
```

I would also like to introduce a convention to inject an ID based on the `EntityType`, which I've tried to do like:

```
yield return FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.ConventionBuilder.Class.When(
      arg => arg.Expect(f => f.EntityType == typeof (ENTITYTYPE)),
      arg => arg.Id // does not work, as .Id is readonly
);
```

So, how do I inject the ID, and possibly also a CombinedID, within a ConventionBuilder?

Edit:

I've also tried this, but sadly the breakpoint in the apply-path (`var a = 1;`) never gets reached:

```
yield return FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.ConventionBuilder.Id.When(
      arg => arg.Expect(f => f.EntityType == typeof(ENTITYTYPE)),
      arg =>
      {
          var a = 1;
      }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by extending the `Mappings`-call a bit:

```
.Mappings(arg =>
{
    var autoPersistenceModel = AutoMap.Source(typeSource);
    foreach (var overrideType in typeSource.GetOverrideTypes())
    {
        autoPersistenceModel.Override(overrideType);
    }
    foreach (var conventionType in typeSource.GetConventionTypes())
    {
        autoPersistenceModel.Conventions.Add(conventionType);
    }
    arg.AutoMappings.Add(autoPersistenceModel);
})
```

Unfortunately this is far from elegant or complete - it would be way more decent if `AutoMap.Source(typeSource)` could handle conventions and overrides from the `GetTypes`-method or if `IIdConvention` would be taken into account on building the maps (which it does not atm)...